# Ricci curvature tensor calculation?

Tags: differential-geometry

Is this correct?
$$ R=R_{ab}g^{ab} $$
$$ R(g_{cd})=R_{ab}g^{ab}(g_{cd}) $$
$$Rg_{cd}=R_{ab}g^{ab}(g_{ab}\delta^a_c\delta^b_d)$$
$$Rg_{cd}=R_{ab}(g^{ab}g_{ab})\delta^a_c\delta^b_d$$
$$Rg_{cd}=R_{ab}n\delta^a_c\delta^b_d$$
$$Rg_{cd}=R_{ab}n(\delta^a_c\delta^b_d)$$
$$Rg_{cd}(\delta^c_a\delta^d_b)=R_{ab}n$$
$$Rg_{ab}=R_{ab}n$$
$$\frac{Rg_{ab}}{n}=R_{ab}$$
So do we have that
$$R_{ab}=\frac{Rg_{ab}}{n}$$

Comment: It is not correct. If your computations were correct any Riemannian manifold would be Einstein, which is not true. Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: The mistake is in your third line -- when you introduce the delta functions, you re-use the dummy index a.  You have to use a new letter for each new dummy index.